# How can I allow spans to wrap to new lines within a single row in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Assuming I have 12 grid columns, how can I allow `n` spans within a single `row` while allowing them to wrap around?

This works:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
```

But can I make this work — providing the same visible output?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: it is happening http://jsfiddle.net/Y8EGm/

Comment: They seem to render as you desire: http://www.bootply.com/117007

Comment: Ugh. Must have other issues going on then. Thanks.